# How to improve the performance when select get few records from three millions records in sql

Tags: sql-server

*I have nearly 3 million records in a table. when i select the records from using the below query it takes atleast 45 secs.*

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
       b.NAME, 
       a.paid_date, 
       (SELECT Count(user_id) 
        FROM   tbl_payment_master 
        WHERE  user_id = a.user_id 
               AND paid_date = a.paid_date 
        GROUP  BY paid_date)                            AS noofpaymnt, 
       (SELECT Count(user_id) 
        FROM   tbl_payment_master 
        WHERE  user_id = a.user_id 
               AND Month(paid_date) = Month(a.paid_date) 
               AND Year(paid_date) = Year(a.paid_date)) AS noofpaymonth 
FROM   tbl_payment_master AS a 
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_registration AS b 
               ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
WHERE  a.premium_amount != 0 
       AND a.user_id = @user_id
```

*My table structure*

```
create table tbl_userregistration(user_id bigint primary key identity,name nvarchar(100)) 

create table tbl_payment_master(payment_id bigint primary key identity,paid_date datetime,amount float,user_id bigint foreign key references tbl_user_registration(user_id))  )
```

*How could be improve the performance.*

Any alter solution to retrieve data's .

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements, including indexes and constraints.  Query performance depends on available indexes as well as the way the query is expressed.

Comment: those correlated subqueries are killing you.

Comment: 1. Add index on `tbl_payment_master(a.user_id, a.premium_account)`. 2. Don't use functions like Month or Year to search. Use persisted computed column. Maybe index will be helpful, depends on range.

Comment: You can use ms sql's tuning advisor, you should get hints with how you should improve your query / tables.

Comment: pls use this before post, http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: if i remove 
(
(select count(user_Id) from tbl_payment_Master 
where user_Id=a.user_Id and premium_amount!=0 and paid_date=a.paid_date group by paid_date) as noofpaymnt,
(select count(user_Id) from tbl_payment_Master 
where user_Id=a.user_Id and premium_amount!=0 and month(paid_Date)=MONTH(a.paid_date) and year(paid_Date)=year(a.paid_date)) as noofpaymonth 
)
this part from the query then it takes only fraction of seconds

Comment: But i need noofpaymnt and  noofpaymonth  columns

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Can you please provide a simple set of sample data and expected output from that data?

Comment: @Manojkumar Also, can you please explain the logic of `noofpaymnt` and `noofpaymnoth` ?

Comment: where is the `premium_amount` in `tbl_payment_master` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing anything else, I did a mechanical refactoring of the correlated subqueries into joins. This MAY or MAY NOT be helpful depending on your setup.
The reason this may work is because with a join, the dataset is calculated generally once, but for a correlated subquery, it is running the sub query once for each record in the return.

This technique demonstrates something called a derived table.

Also, the userid filter in the derived table may or may not be needed or useful.

```
SELECT a.user_id
    ,b.NAME
    ,a.paid_date
    ,paymentDateCount = noofpaymnt.userCount
    ,PaymentMonthCount = noofpaymonth.userCount
FROM tbl_payment_master AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_user_registration AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
        ,paid_date
        ,userCount = Count(user_id)
    FROM tbl_payment_master
    WHERE user_id = @user_id AND a.premium_amount != 0
    GROUP BY user_id
        ,paid_date
    ) noofpaymnt ON a.user_id = noofpaymnt.user_id
    AND a.paid_date = noofpaymnt.paiddate
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
        ,paymentmonth = month(paid_date)
        ,paymentyear = year(paiddate)
        ,userCount = Count(user_id)
    FROM tbl_payment_master
    WHERE user_id = @user_id AND a.premium_amount != 0
    GROUP BY user_id
        ,month(paid_date)
        ,year(paid_date)
    ) noofpaymonth ON a.user_id = noofpaymonth.user_id
    AND month(a.paid_date) = noofpaymonth.paymentmonth
    AND year(a.paid_date) = noofpaymonth.paymentyear
WHERE a.premium_amount != 0
    AND a.user_id = @user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...it's really helpful for me...once again thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm very sure there's a better way to write this, but I think you want something in the lines of this:

```
select
    a.user_id
    , b.name
    , aggr.usr_cnt
    , aggr2.usr_cnt
from tbl_payment_master as a
    inner join tbl_user_registration as b
        on a.user_id = b.user_id
    left join (select 
                    count(aa.user_id) usr_cnt
                    , aa.user_id
                    , aa.paid_date
                from tbl_payment_master aa
                where aa.paid_date = a.paid_date
                    and aa.user_id = @user_id
                group by aa.paid_date, aa.user_id
                ) aggr on aggr.user_id = a.user_id
                    and aggr.paid_date = a.paid_date
    left join (select 
                    count(aa.user_id) usr_cnt
                    , aa.user_id
                    , month(aa.paid_date) paid_date_month
                    , year(aa.paid_date) paid_date_year
                from tbl_payment_master aa
                where month(aa.paid_date) = month(a.paid_date)
                    and year(aa.paid_date) = year(a.paid_date)
                    and aa.user_id = @user_id
                group by aa.user_id
                    , month(aa.paid_date)
                    , year(aa.paid_date)
                ) aggr2 on aggr2.user_id = a.user_id
                    and aggr2.paid_date_month = month(a.paid_date)
                    and aggr2.paid_date_year = year(a.paid_date)
where a.premium_amount <> 0
    and a.user_id = @user_id;
```

*PS: It would be much easier to test and improve this query on real data*

Comment: the second left join should be called differently than the first one

Comment: @Aツ I was just changing that

Comment: and while you are at it, give the columns `MONTH(paid_date)`a name

Comment: @Aツ Still refactoring :) It would be so much easier to test my code on real data... Then I wouldn't have to re-re-re-read my code to spot small mistakes. But **thank you** for being vigilent! :)

Comment: Thanks for Your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Index all fields that are read by the database.
This should speed up performance.